# Possible to have (2) "conditions" in an MSBuild process

Tags: msbuild

Somewhat new to MSBuild. I have a folder for `robots.txt` that uses the `configuration` to copy one of the files to the project's root folder. This is working as expected. However, when I want to run `Debug` it can't find the file, b/c obviously I don't need one for debugging. Instead of adding this dummy file, I wanted to exclude it from the build process if the `configuration` is one or the other listed, as so:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="Web.temp.config" DestinationFiles="Web.config" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="True" />
    <Delete Files="Web.temp.config" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)Content\robots\robots.$(Configuration).txt" Condition="$(Configuration)==Staging" DestinationFiles="robots.txt" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="True" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)Content\robots\robots.$(Configuration).txt" Condition="$(Configuration)==Production" DestinationFiles="robots.txt" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="True" />
  </Target>
```

You can see above that I have (2) separate `<Copy>` elements that are doing the same thing (regarding the `robots.txt` files). Can I use an "OR" clause in this? And if so, how? Is there a better way to go about doing this?

**Desired approach:**

```
<Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)Content\robots\robots.$(Configuration).txt" Condition="$(Configuration)==Production || $(Configuration)==Staging" DestinationFiles="robots.txt" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="True" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSbuild "or clause" is written as `Or` *not* as `||`, otherwise your approach seems fine to me. (fwiw, I'm really not that versed in MSBuild.)

Also, the way I write conditions (though that may be partially cargo cult) is `Condition="'$(Bla)' == 'Value'"`, i.e. I quote the values in the condition.

From your q text you also might try `Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug'"`?

Comment: Nice - I just used the `Or` instead of the `!=` - also single quotes weren't required. Apprec!

Comment: Rob, my suspicion is that you'll need single quotes when you test agains a $(Foo) that could potentially be empty, because *maybe* the condition would be ill-formed otherwise then. (Well, that's that just Batch File gut feeling, maybe MSBUILD is smarter that that :-)